# Ubuntu-desktop packages installation yields broken packages error

Tags: package-management, nautilus, dependencies, libreoffice

For some file sharing I had to install X2Go Client, which removed some packages. I think it also removed ubuntu-desktop packages, since I cannot find the file explorer and libre office anymore.

I'm trying to reinstall these packages by running `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, resulting in

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: nautilus but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of `apt-cache policy nautilus ubuntu-desktop`:

```
nautilus:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4
  Verstion table:
    1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.4 -1
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4 500
      500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
ubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.417
  Version table:
    1.417 500
      500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Installing separate packages (nautilus, libreoffice) also results in similar errors. Actions taken so far:

- Use aptitude for installation
- Remove X2Go Client before installation
- First run `sudo apt install -f`
- First run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
- Run `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
- Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt remove && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`

Using `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94501/discussion-on-question-by-jeroen-ubuntu-desktop-packages-installation-yields-bro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should re-add all necessary repositories with commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe multiverse restricted"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe multiverse restricted"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe multiverse restricted"
```

and retry installation of necessary software with something like:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!